# sIFR 3 wrapped by $ in IE9 beta

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr

It was brought to my attention that sIFR3 titles are wrapped by "$" in IE9 beta. Is there any fix for this or will there be a sIFR update?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what I'm doing...but I'm using IE9 and learning to set up sIFR3 and at first had the $ symbol, but was able to have it dissappear by removing spaces before and after the text.  Maybe this isn't the same issue.....but that's what happened for me.

Comment: Is this an answer? I think it should be a comment if you start it with "I have no idea what I'm doing..."

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there is a blank at the beginning of the text.  It appears magically somewhere in the process.  I used the following to clean up my site : trim text, call sifr replace.

function trimEnds(text)
{
 if(text != null)
  return text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}